# What is the difference between npm-shrinkwrap.json and package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-shrinkwrap, package-lock.json

With the [release of npm@5](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), it will now write a `package-lock.json` unless a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` already exists.

I installed npm@5 globally via:

```
npm install npm@5 -g
```

And now, if a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is found during:

```
npm install
```

a warning will be printed:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm
is compatible with lockfileVersion@1,
but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0.
I'll try to do my best with it!
```

So my take-away is that I should replace the shrinkwrap with the `package-lock.json`.

Yet why is there a new format for it? What can the `package-lock.json` do that the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` cannot?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

The files have exactly the same content, but there are a handful of differences in how npm handles them, most of which are noted on the docs pages for [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json) and [npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npm-shrinkwrap-json):

- `package-lock.json` is never published to npm, whereas `npm-shrinkwrap` is by default
- `package-lock.json` files that are not in the top-level package are ignored, but shrinkwrap files belonging to dependencies are respected
- `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is backwards-compatible with npm versions 2, 3, and 4, whereas `package-lock.json` is only recognized by npm 5+

You can convert an existing `package-lock.json` to an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` by running `npm shrinkwrap`.

Thus:

- If you are not publishing your package to npm, the choice between these two files is of little consequence. You may wish to use `package-lock.json` because it is the default and its name is clearer to npm beginners; alternatively, you may wish to use `npm-shrinkwrap.json` for backwards compatibility with npm 2-4 if it is difficult for you to ensure everyone on your development team is on npm 5+. (Note that npm 5 was released on 25th May 2017; backwards compatibility will become less and less important the further we get from that date, as most people will eventually upgrade.)
- If you *are* publishing your package to npm, you have a choice between:

  1. using a `package-lock.json` to record exactly which versions of dependencies you installed, but allowing people installing your package to use any version of the dependencies that is compatible with the version ranges dictated by your `package.json`, or
  2. using an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to guarantee that everyone who installs your package gets *exactly* the same version of all dependencies

  The official view described in the docs is that option 1 should be used for libraries (presumably in order to reduce the amount of package duplication caused when lots of a package's dependencies all depend on slightly different versions of the same secondary dependency), but that option 2 might be reasonable for executables that are going to be installed globally.

Comment: +1 - can you clarify your second bullet point though? What's the distinction between that behaviour and having an npm-shrinkwrap?

Comment: @Rhys the second bullet won't matter in practice unless you're doing something weird. Basically, it just says that if a library somehow *did* publish a `package-lock.json` (which isn't possible), then if you were to install that library as a dependency of some other package, the library's `package-lock.json` would be ignored by NPM. However, if a library publishes an `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, and you install the library as a dependency, then you will *also* install as secondary dependencies the *exact versions* of all dependencies specified in the library's `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

Comment: Can you please add that [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html) exists to insure the installation of the `package-lock.json` as read-only. (`npm install` mutates the `package-lock.json` causing confusion and potential bugs and does not take advantage of the `package-lock.json` per se.)

Comment: @k0pernikus I don't think there's any difference between how `npm ci` handles `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and `package-lock.json` - what's its relevance to this question about the difference between the two files? Also, after reading around: I think that *"`npm install` ... does not take advantage of the `package-lock.json`"* has been false since npm 5.4 - I believe `npm install` now respects your `package-lock` *unless* it's outright incompatible with your `package.json`, in which case the latter will take precedence. (But I've been out of the JavaScript world for a bit - am I missing something?)

Comment: Mark how can I prevent npm from publishing shrinkwrap? You mentioned by default it does, which is what I am experiencing. And I don't want the shrinkwrap to be included during "npm publish" step. Thanks

Comment: @Mark Amery unfortunately npm install still install the latest version available of a dependency even if the version in package.json are "solid", I mean don't have ^ or ~(that as long I know should indicate to look for the version up if possible), I referring to semantic versioning https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

Comment: @CarmineTambascia No, that isn't true. You can test it easily: create a folder, run `npm init` in it, add `"dependencies": {"lodash": "1.0.0"}` to `package.json`, run `npm install`, and look in the generated `package-lock.json`. You will get Lodash 1.0.0 - not the latest version.

Comment: @Mark Amery if there is a specific version of course. But if the version is with semantic versioning then depending on the versioning is been installed the latest or also if that version is been updated in term of api. Indeed otherwise wouldn't been introduced. But somehow I wasn't correct, its try to install also latest version of peer dependecies indeed one can be now avoid that with legacy-peer-deps

Comment: @CarmineTambascia I'm confused - now you say that *"of course"* if you specify *"a specific version"* you get it, but earlier (in your August 30th comment) you were saying you *"still install the latest version ... even if"* you *"don't have ^ or ~"*, i.e. if you don't use *"semantic versioning"*. If you weren't saying you get the latest version even with a dependency declaration like `"lodash": "1.0.0"`, what were you saying?

Comment: Why is option 2 better for global packages?

Comment: @Ini the *upside* of option 2 (for any kind of package) is that when you install version X of the package you are absolutely guaranteed to get all the same sub-dependency versions (which reduces the risk of bugs or behaviour differences caused by getting different versions of subdependencies to what the package's author tested it with). It's only recommended for executable packages that are meant to be installed globally because *in any other context* there's a big *downside* to option 2 (it will tend to increase the build size of packages that depend on you), but not for global executables.

Answer (score 30):

[Explanation from NPM Developer](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6dgnnq/npm_v500_released_save_by_default_lockfile_better/di3mjuk/):

> The idea is definitely for package-lock.json to be the Latest and
>   Greatest in shrinkwrap technology, and npm-shrinkwrap.json to be
>   reserved for those precious few folks out there who care very much
>   about their libraries having an exact node_modules -- and for people
>   who want CI using npm@>=2 to install a particular tree without having
>   to bump its npm version.
>
> The new lockfile ("package-lock.json") shares basically all of the
>   same code, the exact same format as npm-shrinkwrap (you can rename
>   them between one another!). It's also something the community seems to
>   understand: "it has a lockfile" seems to click so much faster with
>   people. Finally, having a new file meant that we could have relatively
>   low-risk backwards-compat with shrinkwrap without having to do weird
>   things like allow-publication mentioned in the parent post.

Comment: I still am not clear on the difference. If `npm-shrinkwrap` is for exact node_modules....I assume `package-lock.json` is locking less than exact? And if so, what is not locking that `npm-shrinkwrap` is locking?

Comment: you got it wrong @dman. package-lock is the new version of npm-shrinkwrap. package-lock is opt-out (so you have to remove the feature because it's default enabled), npm-shrinkwrap is opt-in (so you have to enable it because it's not included my default). the reason why they introduced package-lock is that 1. user now have a saver way to deal with dependencies because it's enabled by default and 2. the name implies what it is in oposite to "shrinkwrap". npm-shrinkwrap had some special dependency-behavior settings what package-lock doesn't have now. npm-shrinkwrap is now obsolete.

Comment: this is incorrect. By saying that package-lock is the new version of npm-shrinkwrap, you are saying it is a replacement. npm-shrinkwrap is not deprecated and has differences with package-lock.json. Furthermore, package-lock.json [has a bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17091) while npm-shrinkwrap does not... thus emphasizing  more so they are not the same code.

Comment: Also package-lock.json is intrusive. So it can easily cause scm conflicts if you call "npm i" while shrinkwrap should be explicitly generated and will not cause conflicts on ci servers. Yes, I can be wrong here.

Comment: @dman *"package-lock.json has a bug while npm-shrinkwrap does not"* - no it doesn't. There's no indication of that in the issue you've linked to; it doesn't even mention `npm-shrinkwrap`. As I note in my answer, converting a `package-lock.json` to an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is literally just done by renaming the file; they *are* "the same code".

Comment: after so many reading, I had to have exact same dependecies of a project pass to another one, then I went for npm ci as I have read. Unfortunately I ended-up with an empty node_modules, but not a new one. Of course running npm i,with package.json with non depdencies have ~ or ^ thus indicating not to look for update if existing(but I may be wrong on this) a new modified package-lock.json.

Comment: Of course this wasn't what I want as I have some legacy dependecies thatbfor the sake of development I want to keep. The only solution I found was simply to remove again node_module and copy manully the package-lock.json from the other project and run npm install. Someone could tell me if this at the moment achievable via command line and what the step to take?

Answer (score 14):

I think the idea was to have --save and shrinkwrap happen by default but avoid any potential issues with a shrinkwrap happening where it wasn't wanted. So, they just gave it a new file name to avoid any conflicts. Someone from npm explained it more thoroughly here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6dgnnq/npm_v500_released_save_by_default_lockfile_better/di3mjuk/

The relevant quote:

> npm publishes most files in your source directory by default, and
>   people have been publishing shrinkwraps for years. We didn't want to
>   break compatibility. With --save and shrinkwrap by default, there was
>   a great risk of it accidentally making it in and propagating through
>   the registry, and basically render our ability to update deps and
>   dedupe... null.
>
> So we chose a new name. And we chose a new name kind of all of a
>   sudden. The new lockfile shares basically all of the same code, the
>   exact same format

Answer (score 7):

`package-lock.json` versions are guaranteed with only `npm ci` ([since `npm install` overwrites `package-lock.json` if there is a conflict with `package.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json/53594050#53594050)).

`npm-shrinkwrap.json` versions are guaranteed with both `npm ci` and `npm install`.

Comment: -1; I just checked and this isn't true, at least for npm 10.2.0. Quick test: in a new folder, run `npm init --yes && npm install lodash && npm shrinkwrap`. Now, in `package.json`, modify `"lodash": "^4.17.21"` (or whatever later version you see, if you are doing this in the future) to say `"lodash": "3.0.0"`. Now run `npm install`; observe the "changed 1 package" message in the output. Check your `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and you will see it has been updated to specify version `3.0.0` of Lodash, not whatever got installed before.

Comment: (I'm not really sure how you'd be meant to work with an `npm-shrinkwrap` file if it _did_ work the way this answer describes. What would the workflow for updating a dependency version be if `npm install` didn't write to the shrinkwrap file? Updating your lock file as you change your dependencies is a necessary part of development and if your answer *were* accurate that necessary behaviour would simply not be supported when using a Shrinkwrap file.)