# Bootstrap 4 on Single Page Application Angular + .Net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, bootstrap-4

Anyone tried to make an application with

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
dotnet new angular
```

? like in this example https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

This command makes an angular + .net core project with bootstrap 3.
I'm trying to put bootstrap 4 instead.

I tried to put bootstrap 4 css over vendor.css (where bootstrap 3 is located) but without succes.

Does anyone know how to put bootstrap 4 over bootstrap 3?, eventually with the javascript plugins jquery and popper.

It would be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of clarity, this is what worked for me.

1. Open your Angular SPA solution in Visual Studio
2. Open `package.json` and update the bootstrap entry to `"bootstrap": "4.0.0"`, or whichever version you require
3. Close the solution in Visual Studio
4. Open the project folder and delete the `node_modules` folder
5. Open up a command prompt for the project folder
6. Run `npm install popper.js --save` in command prompt
7. Run `npm install` in command prompt
8. Run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` in command prompt
9. Open the solution in Visual Studio
10. Build the solution, after which you should be fully upgraded

A couple of notes:

- This requires that you have node/npm and webpack installed globally (I think!)
- On a couple of occasions I saw errors from npm/webpack in command prompt. When this occurred I just re-ran the failing command and continued once it was successful.
- If you're using source control, you'll notice that the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` has been heavily modified. I believe this is to do with upgraded versions of npm, but I'm no expert. Here's some further reading on the subject [What is the difference between npm-shrinkwrap.json and package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258235/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-shrinkwrap-json-and-package-lock-json)

I've also put together a working sample of the template on GitHub here https://github.com/alterius/AngularSPABootstrap4

Answer (score 3):

You can update the bootstrap version in your `package.json` like this

```
 "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
```

and delete your node_modules and do a `npm install` again.

That's it. You don't need to touch the `webpack.config.vendor.js` because it already referenced  the bootstrap css `'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',`

Whenever you add/remove something in webpack, you need to generate the bundle.

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

And run

```
webpack
```

to generate the main bundle.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't working :|.   For npm install i have new bootstrap in node modules, but the site uses bootstrap 3 because in vendor.css is bootstrap 3.  If i put bootstrap 4 in vendor css i get other errors.     I should give up on "dotnet new angular" command and start from 0? (API + Client side Angular). That approach has some big benefits over the manual approach with API + Client side angular, without vendor.js etc.

Comment: It is possible to overrite the generated files vendor js, vendor css, main client.js..     I want to restart the process, to make new files. I think the webpack makes this files the first time we run the application. How i can tell him to do it again ?

Comment: @Marian i forgot to mention running the webpack again. I'll update my answer so that others can see

Comment: I followed the instructions above but with Bootstrap4-beta3 you also have to install popper.js. Therefore just add "npm install popper.js --save" just before the "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js" step and it all works

Comment: @FrankCannon glad it helped you. You could also try other library like ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap so you don't need to add jquery, bootstrap.js and popper.js in your project. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since some js components in Bootstrap 4 depends on Tether.js add
`"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"` and  `"tether": "^1.4.0"` to your `package.json`
then  delete `node_modules` folder and run
`nmp install`
then because of Bootstrap checking for `tether` add this to plugins in your `webpack.config.vendor.js`

```
plugins: [
    <... your plugins here>,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "Tether": 'tether'
    })
]
```

then run

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
webpack
```

references are: [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/626) , [this](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/issues/48) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h)