# Installing Bootstrap 4 with VS 2017 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm working on my first side project attempting to use the following tools:

- .Net Core 2 MVC
- Angular 4
- Bootstrap 4
- Visual Studio 2017

I followed this tutorial with no issue to get the Angular app running:
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-4-app-with-visual-studio-2017/

I'm very unfamiliar with Angular4, webpack, etc. in general. I've worked on many knockout, Angular 1, and Angular 2 projects, but I've never set up the Angular 2+ projects myself.

What I can't figure out is how to install bootstrap 4 using npm. Running npm install on the latest bootstrap libraries went fine, but I don't know how to inject the CSS and js into the application. Most of the guides on getting started with bootstrap 4 use files that aren't generated in the above tutorial (e.g. styles.css from this: http://technobytz.com/install-bootstrap-4-using-npm.html).

Here is the current view of the project from visual studio:

[image: project]

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use one of this getting started guides: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305228/1242757) by [@james-law](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138519/james-law) to a similar question solved the problem.

> 1. Open your Angular SPA solution in Visual Studio
> 2. Open `package.json` and update the bootstrap entry to `"bootstrap": "4.0.0"`, or whichever version you require
> 3. Close the solution in Visual Studio
> 4. Open the project folder and delete the `node_modules` folder
> 5. Open up a command prompt for the project folder
> 6. Run `npm install popper.js --save` in command prompt
> 7. Run `npm install` in command prompt
> 8. Run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` in command prompt
> 9. Open the solution in Visual Studio
> 10. Build the solution, after which you should be fully upgraded

Although the answer worked great I didn't want to install webpack globally so I skipped step 8 and instead deleted the `dist` folder inside `wwwroot` before step 10.