# How to lock down npm dependencies in a cloud function

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions, yarnpkg

Is there any way to control what version of dependencies (and transient dependencies) are installed when deploying a cloud function?

Since the [cloud function runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#the_cloud_functions_runtime) uses node `v6.11.5`, I assume it is using npm `v3.10.10` distributed with that version of node. This version of npm does not support [`package.lock`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) (added in [npm `v5.0.0`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v5.6.0/CHANGELOG.md#v500-2017-05-25)).

I set all versions to fixed versions (removing the `^`) in my `package.json` and added [`save-exact=true`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact) to my `.npmrc` file, but this will only control direct dependencies. Transient dependencies are not locked in this manner.

Is there any way to control all installed dependency versions in cloud functions? Is [npm `shrinkwrap.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/shrinkwrap.json) honored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted [a question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cloud-functions-beta-testers/Vv3cV_Dpids/l59TVQ40AQAJ) in the [Cloud Functions Beta Testers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-functions-beta-testers) group and they confirmed that **the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is not honored when deploying to Cloud Functions.**

Response from the Product Manager:

> Currently, we don't support the npm-shrinkwrap.json file. We're looking at making some improvements to dependency management as we think about our runtime strategy, and this is a suggestion that we'll definitely consider.

As they recommended, I created [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73717432) on their public issue tracker. Add your support to that issue (by starring it) if this is something you want too!

As a senior node.js developer, having a means to have reproducible installations is essential to delivering production worthy code.

Answer (score 0):

`npm-shrinkwrap.json` and `package-lock.json` [behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258235/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-shrinkwrap-json-and-package-lock-json) only from the point of view of an NPM package author/mantainer

`package-lock.json` **won't be published to the NPM** registry *(but it will stay with the source code)* and guarantee that any **author/mantainer** of the project will get the **same dependencies**.

`npm-shrinkwrap.json` is instead meant **to be published to the NPM** registry and guarantee that **not only authors/mantainers** but also the **users** who install the package get the **same dependencies**.

Since your project is not related with authoring an NPM package, you can rely on `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to have a reproducible dependency tree using any `NPM` version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know if Google Cloud Functions respects npm-shrinkwrap.json (they use an old version of node, so I'm confident the package-lock.json will be ignored).

Comment: npm@3.x supports `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

Comment: yes, I agree... it _should_ work. My question was looking for confirmation from Google that cloud functions are simply `npm install`ed. It's not documented anywhere that I can find :-(