# Understanding NPM shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

Recently discovered `npm-audit` and on the first run it flagged a lot of vulnerabilities, mostly around packages and their dependencies.

Wanting to get these vulnerabilities resolved I have discovered `npm shrinkwrap` which allows me to specify what versions and its dependencies should use? That's how I see it anyway (Please correct me if wrong, here to learn).

One example I am trying to fix is the module `hoek`, in my `package.json` this is set as `"hoek": "^5.0.3"`

When I run `npm shrinkwrap` one of the dependencies has `hoek` set as version 2

```
"boom": {
  "version": "2.10.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-2.10.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-OciRjO/1eZ+D+UkqhI9iWt0Mdm8=",
  "requires": {
    "hoek": "2.x.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hoek": {
      "version": "2.16.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-2.16.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-ILt0A9POo5jpHcRxCo/xuCdKJe0="
    }
  }
},
```

I thought I could edit this and specify what version i want the dependency to use like so

```
  "boom": {
  "version": "2.10.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-2.10.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-OciRjO/1eZ+D+UkqhI9iWt0Mdm8=",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "hoek": "2.x.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hoek": {
      "version": "5.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-5.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-ILt0A9POo5jpHcRxCo/xuCdKJe0=",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
},
```

However when I run `npm shrinkwrap` or `npm install` all this reverts to the original

How do I go about managing this? Is shrinkwrap the right choice or am I trying to do things with it I simply cannot?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? If it's npm@5 you may want to use `package.lock` (enabled by default unless shrinkwrap within project) instead of shrinkwrap.

Comment: For further information see: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks

Comment: @k0pernikus thank you. Is it possible then to lock the version of hoek then for a dependency, like the example in the question ?

Comment: This is a good explanation of npm shrinkwrap https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132512/664054

Answer (score 19, accepted):

NPM **shrinkwrap** is used to lock the dependency version in a project.

After installing packages using **npm install** or **npm install package-name** and updating your node_modules folder, you should run npm shrinkwrap

It will create new **npm-shrinkwrap.json** file with information about all packages you use and you have to commit the file.

Next time, when someone calls **npm install**, it will install packages from **npm-shrinkwrap.json** and you will have the same environment on all machines.

Comment: Thanks for answering Raja, however my problem is that after I have edited the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and commited it, running `npm install` overides it

Comment: You should not edit  npm-shrinkwrap.json, you have to auto generate it by running npm shrinkwrap.

Comment: I do have another question.. What is the point `shrinkwrap` when we have a `package.json` file ? How do they differ?

Comment: @Richlewis The accepted answer doesn't seem to answer your question.

Comment: @Richlewis: Were you able to resolve this issue ?? I am facing same problem. Whenever i change version in npm-shrinkwrap.json file and do npm install. It reverts back to previous version only. Could you please help me ?

Comment: @PinkiSharma the package.json is the source of truth. npm-shrinkwrap.json and package-lock.json are generated from that. You should change the version in your package.json, run `npm install` (which updates the package-lock.json) and then run `npm shrinkwrap` which will update your npm-shrinkwrap.json

Comment: @RajaSekar I thought the purpose of "when someone calls npm install, it will install packages from npm-shrinkwrap.json and you will have the same environment on all machines." was `package-lock.json` Whats the difference between "npm-shrinkwrap.json" and "package-lock.json"?

Comment: "npm install" when you have a npm-shrinkwrap.json is similar to "npm ci" when you want to install from the package-lock.json. Iff you use the right version of node that was used.

Comment: @Marc According to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-shrinkwrap the shrinkwrap is a tighter variant preferred over any package-lock.json. Though the benefits seems little to me, there might be some benefit in context of continuous development and staged deployments. Additional information is [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-locks).

Answer (score 2):

npm-shrinwrap.json is honored by `npm publish` - means it will be included into final package.

package.json will be ignored by `npm publish` and as result your final package will not have any means to "lock" package versions.

Comment: Answer [checks out at docs.npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-shrinkwrap#description): "_This command repurposes package-lock.json into a publishable npm-shrinkwrap.json or simply creates a new one. The file created and updated by this command will then take precedence over any other existing or future package-lock.json files._"